# How to create a dynamic LINQ join extension method

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

There was a library of dynamic [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) extensions methods released as a sample with [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008). I'd like to extend it with a join method. The code below fails with a parameter miss match exception at run time. Where is the problem?

```
public static IQueryable Join(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable inner,
                              string outerSelector, string innerSelector, string resultsSelector,
                              params object[] values)
{
    if (inner == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
    if (outerSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("outerSelector");
    if (innerSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("innerSelector");
    if (resultsSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("resultsSelctor");

    LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda =
        DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(outer.ElementType, null,
                                      outerSelector, values);
    LambdaExpression innerSelectorLambda =
        DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType,
                                      null, innerSelector, values);

    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] {
        Expression.Parameter(outer.ElementType, "outer"),
        Expression.Parameter(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType,
        "inner")
    };
    LambdaExpression resultsSelectorLambda =
        DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(parameters, null,
                                      resultsSelector, values);

    return outer.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Join", new Type[] {
                outer.ElementType,
                inner.AsQueryable().ElementType,
                outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type,
                innerSelectorLambda.Body.Type,
                resultsSelectorLambda.Body.Type
            },
            outer.Expression, inner.AsQueryable().Expression,
            Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda),
            Expression.Quote(innerSelectorLambda),
            Expression.Quote(resultsSelectorLambda))
        );
}
```

Comment: could you paste the exact error message?

Comment: Can you post an example of using your join.  I would like to use it, but I am such a greenhorn at LINQ.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Did you know this made it into a book?  I found it referenced in "Modern Data Access with Entity Framework Core" 2018.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've fixed it myself now. It was a schoolboy error passing too many parameters to the CreateQuery(... ) call. Paste the following code into the Dynamic.cs file within the DynamicQueryable class for a dynamic Join extension method. You can find the source for the DynamicQuery sample project at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples.

Enjoy.

```
    public static IQueryable Join(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable inner, string outerSelector, string innerSelector, string resultsSelector, params object[] values)
    {
        if (inner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
        if (outerSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("outerSelector");
        if (innerSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("innerSelector");
        if (resultsSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultsSelctor");

        LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(outer.ElementType, null, outerSelector, values);
        LambdaExpression innerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, null, innerSelector, values);

        ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] {
            Expression.Parameter(outer.ElementType, "outer"), Expression.Parameter(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, "inner") };
        LambdaExpression resultsSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(parameters, null, resultsSelector, values);

        return outer.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Join",
                new Type[] {outer.ElementType, inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type, resultsSelectorLambda.Body.Type  },
                outer.Expression, inner.AsQueryable().Expression, Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(innerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(resultsSelectorLambda)));
    }


    //The generic overload.
    public static IQueryable<T> Join<T>(this IQueryable<T> outer, IEnumerable<T> inner, string outerSelector, string innerSelector, string resultsSelector, params object[] values)
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>)Join((IQueryable)outer, (IEnumerable)inner, outerSelector, innerSelector, resultsSelector, values);
    }
```

Comment: Example of usage is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996403/counting-percent-of-rows-with-category-out-of-total-number-of-rows-using-dynamic/6047324#6047324

Comment: Simple usage of this code is as follows: `var result = myDbContext.Person
                .Join(myDbContext.Roles,"new(Id as firstKey,SomeOtherId as secondKey)","new(PersonId as firstKey,AlternativeId as secondKey)", "new (inner as r, outer as p)");` note that if it is joined on multiple columns you must us "as [somekey]" if they are not named the same or an error will occur. Also in the result selector you use the keywords "outer" and "inner"

Comment: How to implement if I want to compare case insensitive string in Join?

Comment: How can i do the same if my number of tables are also dynamic?

Comment: Use `DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda` instead of `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda`

Answer (score 4):

You can install the nuget package of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core - https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

This has the join method implemented along with various other helper methods.

Using this library you can do a simple join in the following the way

`myContext.TableA.Join(myContext.TableB,'Id','TableAId','outer',null)`

in the result selector `outer` and `inner` are key words to access the result of the join.

Using a key with multiple properties and/or selecting a result with multiple properties can be done in the following way

`myContext.TableA.Join(myContext.TableB,'new (Id as key1,Code as key2)','new (TableAId as key1,AnotherCol as key2)','new(outer.Id,inner.Desc)',null)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code showing a join on multiple columns. Using a datatable and datarows you need to always access fields via the indexer.

```
  DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
  t1.Columns.Add("FundId", typeof(int));
  t1.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
  t1.Columns.Add("CodeA", typeof(string));
  t1.Rows.Add(1, new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), "A1");
  t1.Rows.Add(2, new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), "A2");
  t1.Rows.Add(3, new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), "A3");

  DataTable t2 = new DataTable();
  t2.Columns.Add("FundId", typeof(int));
  t2.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
  t2.Columns.Add("CodeB", typeof(string));
  t2.Rows.Add(1, new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), "B1");
  t2.Rows.Add(2, new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), "B2");
  t2.Rows.Add(3, new DateTime(2010, 01, 01), "B3");

  IQueryable outerTable = t1.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
  IEnumerable innerTable = t2.AsEnumerable();

  var query = outerTable.Join
    (
      innerTable, 
      "new(get_Item(0) as FundId, get_Item(1) as Date)",
      "new(get_Item(0) as FundId, get_Item(1) as Date)",
      "new(outer.get_Item(0) as FundId, outer.get_Item(2) as CodeA, inner.get_Item(2) as CodeB)"
    );
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. Here you use the Join method provided by Linq, the question - was about creating this method, because it wasn't provided by Linq yet.