# Creating a generic class to return a table

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create a generic class where I can pass two tables and return the first one. The two variables are string values that I use to join the tables in the linq query. What I want to return is a IQueryable value but it keeps returning a DataQuery value.

This ends failing in my MVC view with the error "Method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL"

Code below:

```
    var result = GetTable<Table1, Table2>("Table1id", "Table2id");


    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetTable<T, A>(string table1Variable,
                                        string table2Variable) 
                                                  where T : class
                                                  where A : class
    {
        var table1 = entityDatabaseDC.GetTable<T>();
        var table2 = entityDatabaseDC.GetTable<A>();

        return from entity in table1.AsQueryable()
               join entity2 in table2 on entity.GetType().GetProperty(table1Variable)
                                      equals  entity2.GetType().GetProperty(table2Variable)
               select entity;

    }
```

It works fine for a single table:

```
     var result = repository.GetTable<Table1>();

     public virtual IQueryable<T> GetTable<T>() where T : class
    {
           return entityDatabaseDC.GetTable<T>();
    }
```

I'm wondering if what I am trying is possible.

Comment: I think you want to use Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: Just a remark: what's the benefit of using Linq-2-sql if you want something so loosely typed anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input. After looking at bit more into this problem I've decided to take a step back and go back to the drawing board to think if this is correct solution for what I'm trying to achieve and whether it is beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try something like this:

```
   public virtual IQueryable<T> GetTable<T, A>(string table1Variable,
                                        string table2Variable) 
                                                  where T : class
                                                  where A : class
    {
        var table1 = entityDatabaseDC.GetTable<T>();
        var table2 = entityDatabaseDC.GetTable<A>();

        return from entity in table1.AsQueryable()
               join entity2 in table2 on 
               entity.GetType().GetProperty(table1Variable).GetValue(table1,null)
                                      equals 
               entity2.GetType().GetProperty(table2Variable).GetValue(table2,null)
               select entity;

    }
```

Notis the `.GetValue(table1,null)` after the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that linq-to-sql tries to translate the join expression (well, the whole statement) into SQL. Of course there is no way to do a `GetProperty` call from a SQL statement.

So I'm afraid this is never going to work. But maybe you can do it as propsed here: [How to create a dynamic LINQ join extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389094/how-to-create-a-dynamic-linq-join-extension-method).