# Dynamic Linq - Joining a table with 1 to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, join, dynamic-linq

I'm using Dynamic Linq as the backend to an in-app reporting tool and I've hit a problem that I can't get round where I have to access a table that has a 1:M relationship .

My simplified data structure is this:

[image: Database schema]

If I were querying this in standard Linq I'd write the query as:

```
from a in context.Table_A
select new 
{
    a.RefNo,
    val = from b in a.Table_B
          where (b.A_ID == a.ID)
          where (b.code == "A0001"
          select(b.Value).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

This works without any problem. However, when I try the query using Dynamic Linq I can't get the join to work.

From the code below you can see what I'm getting at but obviously I can't use the "a." and the "a.Table_B" references in the query. What do I have to do to be able to access Table_B in this context?

```
string select =  "new (Ref_No, 
                       val = from b in a.Table_B
                       where (b.A_ID == a.ID)
                       where (b.code == \"A0001\"
                       select(b.Value).FirstOrDefault()";

var results = context.Table_A.Select(select);
```

**Edit 1:**

To answer @Hogan's comment - Why don't I use join: The reports system is dynamic and the select statement may or may not be joining on to Table_B (or indeed joining on to Table_B multiple times) so the join has to be optional. My other issue with this is that unlike the Select method where I can pass in a string as a parameter (allowing me to make it dynamic quite easily) the Join() method can't be called in that way. The closest thing I've found is a [dynamic Linq join extention method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389094/how-to-create-a-dynamic-linq-join-extension-method), something I may have to consider using but I've a feeling that this will be cumbersome with the dynamic select().

**Edit 2:**

Based on Hogan's suggestions I've got this far:

```
delegate string searchTableA(Table_A a);

public void Search()
{
   ....

   searchTableA sel = (a) =>
   {
      return (from b in context.Table_B
      where (b.A_ID == a.ID)
      select (b.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
   };

   var res = context.Table_A.Select(sel);
}
```

This gives the error: `'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TestDynamicLinqJoins.Table_A>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Select(System.Linq.IQueryable, string, params object[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Why don't you use the join feature of linq?

Comment: No, sorry. The project got canned after a while so I never carried it on.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give exact code because I don't know the types of your elements, but something like this would work fine using delegates.

```
delegate string searchTableA(elementType a);

searchTableA sel = (a) => 
  {
     return from b in a.Table_B
                   where (b.A_ID == a.ID)
                   where (b.code == "A0001")
                   select(b.Value).FirstOrDefault();
  };

var results = context.Table_A.Select(sel);
```

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush - I can't help unless I can see more of the code.  You are posting one line which means nothing.  Please modify the question to include new source with the question or create a new question with more detail.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I've updated the question with the current code.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush - I see, you don't want `searchTableA(Table_A a)` to take a table, you want it to take an element of `Table_A`... a row or whatever `Table_A` enumerates over.