# How to dynamically create Joins in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to dynamically create Joins in LINQ. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412868) gave me a good insight as to where to start. However, I'm having a problem specifically when the "foreing key" is an `int?`
 (`int` works). When it's an `int?` it will trigger an exception.

I've made a simple LINQ to Objects example to show the problem. In order to run my example, you will need to [install the dynamic linq Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) because I use it for the `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda` method.

This is the code that **triggers the exception**:

```
public class Contact
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int? ContactId { get; set; }

   public string Zip { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var contacts = new List<Contact>();
       var addresses = new List<Address>();

       LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(Contact), null, "Id", new object[0]);
       LambdaExpression innerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(Address), null, "ContactId", new object[0]);
       ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(Contact), "outer"), Expression.Parameter(typeof(Address), "inner") };
       LambdaExpression resultsSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(parameters, null, "outer.Id", new object[0]);

       // BLOWS UP HERE
       var queryExpression = Expression.Call(
           typeof(Queryable), "Join",
           new Type[] { typeof(Contact), typeof(Address), typeof(int?), typeof(int) },
           contacts.AsQueryable().Expression, addresses.AsQueryable().Expression,
           Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(innerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(resultsSelectorLambda));

       // it will not reach the following line
       var queryable = contacts.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery(queryExpression);
   }
}
```

To make the above code **to work**, just replace the 2 occurrences of `int?` by `int`. Everything will work fine. The problem lies in the fact that `Address.ContactId` is `int?`.

The question is: **Why is this happening and how can I fix it?**.

Exception information (in portuguese):

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233079
 Message=Nenhum método genérico 'Join' no tipo 'System.Linq.Queryable' é compatível com os argumentos e os argumentos de tipo fornecidos. Nenhum argumento de tipo deve ser fornecido se o método for não genérico. 
 Source=System.Core
 StackTrace:
      em System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.FindMethod(Type type, String methodName, Type[] typeArgs, Expression[] args, BindingFlags flags)
      em System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Type type, String methodName, Type[] typeArguments, Expression[] arguments)
      em problems.Program.Main(String[] args) na d:\POCs\problems\problems\Program.cs:linha 38
      em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
      em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
      em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
      em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
 InnerException:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the type of your key is `int?`, but the `ParseLambda` method that you're using to create the key selector is creating an expression of type `Expression<Func<Contact, int>>` for your outer key selector.  It's not mapping the result to a nullable int.  That function is then not compatible with the signature of the `Join` method, so it throws an exception.

If, for the sake of your example, you use the following expression for your selector, it will work fine:

```
Expression<Func<Contact, int?>> outerSelectorLambda = c => c.Id;
```

Looking at the API for `ParseLambda`, you should be using the second parameter to specify the return type of the lambda, so just don't leave it `null`:

```
DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(Contact), typeof(int?),
    "Id", new object[0]);
```

Comment: Damn it @Sevry! My coworker and I spent so many hours trying to have this figured. Thank you so much! You rock!